# Detecting Wireless computers which have not established any connection to a Wireless Network

Tags: windows, networking, network-programming, wireless, wifi

All I know is that it is not possible to detect any wireless computer unless they are connected together in a network. I want to know; Is there any possible way, that I could turn on my Wireless Adapter, and search what are other wireless device types around me and some sort of an ID such as MAC or computer name etc. without creating or connecting any Network such as Wireless Ad-Hoc network etc. like we do in Bluetooth? -
If it is possible, then how to implement using C# or any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the operating system and NIC drivers that you're using, you can set the 802.11 NIC to Promiscuous Mode and Monitor Mode in order to capture all packets on a given channel.

At least under Linux, this functionality is supposed by most drivers in conjunction with LibPCap; although Windows is another matter altogether (you'd have to use a version of Windows featuring NDIS6 - i.e. Windows Vista or Windows 7, and an external packet capturing API such as the one provided by the Microsoft Network Monitor SDK).

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer and details. Will this work if all the Wireless PCs around are only just switched ON and NOT connect to any sort of network? I mean, are they broadcasting there status during that time or is there anyway I can send a request to broadcast details to idle wireless NICs around. Thanks

Comment: You'll want to monitor for Probe Request packets (directed to access points from stations/clients) and Probe Response packets (directed from access points to stations/clients). You can also monitor for Beacons, if you're interested in devices that are either operating in Ad-Hoc mode, or as both an access point and a station (e.g. some portable game consoles such as the Nintendo DS).

Comment: However, there's no guarantee that a switched-on client will send Probe Requests (since it's likely that a device may have its radio disabled, be misconfigured, or be otherwise actively participating within a network).

Comment: Thank you very much this is important information for me. Do you know any online website or document where I can learn these in detail?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. The best reference is probably the IEEE 802.11 specifications themselves (which are available free-of-charge from http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html).

Comment: @Tyson you're correct, but for Windows there is no need in NDIS6 or Vista/Win7. Vista has introduced the NetMon but that's really just another sniffing software and definitely not the only one. You can use WireShark, for example, to capture the packets over WinXP.